# insert values of a column into other column

Tags: linux, awk

I have a tab-delimited .txt file with two columns and long list of values in both columns

```
col1    col2
1       a
2       b
3       c
...     ...
```

I want to convert this now to

```
col1
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

So that he insert the values from column 2 into column 1 at the correct location.

Is there any way to do this, maybe using awk, or something else through the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask `awk` to print first column and then second column. By using `print` for each case, you ensure you have a new line in between them:

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $1; print $2}' file
```

Or the following if you just want to print the 1st column on the first line:

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==1 {print $1; next} {print $1; print $2}' file
```

The second command returns the following for your given input:

```
col1
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do:

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\n" '{$1=$1}7' file
```